# Why does [url pathComponents] contain an "/"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, nsurl

Take for example

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"eg://resources/users/1/answers/2"];
NSLog(@"%@", [url pathComponents]);

>> ( "/", "users", "a", "answers", "b" )
```

1) Why does the path contain a "/"?

2) If what I want is the "users", is it safe to use the first index?

```
[[url pathComponents] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Its safe from the point that your iPhone won't explode when you hardcode the index :)

Comment: hehe. my feet uncontrollably trembles when i see a magic number, esp on something that takes up to a week to update =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) In this case the "/" is the root directory.  The other slashes between directories in the path are just separators but the root folder is significant.   "users/1/answers/2" may refer to a different location than "/users/1/answers/2", the former is relative to the current directory and the latter always starts at the root folder.

(2) Yes, if the URL is an absolute URL, not for a relative URL.  But you can get the absolute URL with the absoluteURL method first and then get the components.  Although, what if the URL was just "http://www.example.com/", all you would get is ("/") and that's it, no subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for e great answer! Makes perfect sense now. "But you can get the absolute URL with the absoluteURL method first and then get the components" - good info